# Microsoft Graph API for teams how to talk with Guest?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, azure-communication-services

We would like to implement a chat functionality for random user on our Angular App using Azure Communication Service, which will be linked with Teams where an employee will answer.

So when a random user arrive on the website and click on the chat button, a new chat should be created in Teams.

When I read the documentation to create a chat with a Guest (Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-a-group-chat-with-tenant-guest-user), I can see that an ID is needed for the guest User.

It seems that the email is needed to create a new account, I won't have the user's email, and I don't want it, I only want the user be able to chat with the employee. Documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

As I don't have the email, I won't be able to invite the random user too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

So what is the endpoint to use in Microsoft Graph Api to create a guest to be able to chat with an employee?

Comment: In order to create chat with Teams user, guest user should have an existing email. You can follow this doc to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)/[invite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) a user to the tenant as guest user. After that you can [create chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-a-group-chat-with-tenant-guest-user)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I create or invite a user, can I skip sending an email to confirm?

Comment: On invitation creation, Microsoft Graph automatically sends an invitation email directly to the invited user, or your app can use the inviteRedeemUrl returned in the creation response to craft your own invitation (through your communication mechanism of choice) to the invited user.

Comment: Excellent the second option will be the solution!

Comment: Hi, I got the Invitation returned by GraphServiceClient.Invitations.PostAsync(). I did an HttpClient.GetAsync(Invitation.InviteRedeemUrl) and received a code 200. But the user is still in PendingAcceptance. Didn't find how to to redeem the invitation by Code in documentation, any Idea?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any doc available which explains redeeming the invitation by code.